# How should I print a string that matches this pattern in a file?

Tags: python, regex

Given a file with content like this:

```
{
    "title": "Pilot",
    "image": [
        {
            "resource": "http://images2.nokk.nocookie.net/__cb20110227141960/notr/images/8/8b/pilot.jpg",
            "description": "not yet implemented"
        }
    ],
    "content": "<p>The pilot ...</p>"
},
{
    "title": "Special Christmas (Part 1)",
    "image": [
        {
            "resource": "http://images1.nat.nocookie.net/__cb20090519172121/obli/images/e/ed/SpecialChristmas.jpg",
            "description": "not yet implemented"
        }
    ],
    "content": "<p>Last comment...</p>"
}
```

I have this script to replace all the values of resource,
like this,

```
"resource": "http://images1.nat.nocookie.net/__cb20090519172121/obli/images/e/ed/SpecialChristmas.jpg"
```

for another like this: **`"../img/SpecialChristmas.jpg"`**

```
from StringIO import StringIO    
import re
import urllib

infile = open('test2.txt')
outfile = open('test3.txt', 'w')

pattern = r'"resource": ".+/(.+).jpg"'
replacement = '"resource": "../img/\g<1>.jpg"'
prog = re.compile(".+/(.+).jpg")

for line in infile:
    if prog.match(line):
        print (line) #this prints nothing
    text = re.sub(pattern, replacement, line)
    outfile.write(text)
infile.close()
outfile.close
```

But I also want to print the value of every resource in the loop,
like this:

```
"http://images1.nat.nocookie.net/__cb20090519172121/obli/images/e/ed/SpecialChristmas.jpg"
"http://images1.nat.nocookie.net/__cb20090519172121/obli/images/e/ed/SpecialChristmas.jpg"
```

What I'm doing doesn't work, so what would be the right way to print every resource value
just in console?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should probably just be handling all of that with `json`, since it's JSON.

Comment: Don't know python, but for a start, try prog regex of `[\S\s]+`, this should at least get a print out of non-empty lines. Create a small test file. See what happens.

Comment: You know how they say "don't parse xml with regular expressions?" Well, don't parse JSON with regular expressions, either.

Comment: Is that two *JSON objects*? The json module doesn't seem to like that complete string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have groups within groups and just modify your original `pattern` regex.  This can get a bit confusing so it is easier to use named groups ie. `(?P<group_name>pattern)`

```
import re
import urllib

infile = open('test2.txt')
outfile = open('test3.txt', 'w')

pattern = r'"resource": "(?P<path>.+/(?P<filename>.+)\.jpg)"'
replacement = '"resource": "../img/\g<filename>.jpg"'
prog = re.compile(pattern)

for line in infile:
    match = prog.match(line)
    if match:
        print (match.group('path'))
    text = prog.sub(replacement, line)
    outfile.write(text)
infile.close()
outfile.close
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from json import dumps, loads
with open('that_file') as datfile:
  dat = loads('[' + datfile.read() + ']') # Need some outer braces to make it valid JSON
for item in dat:
  for img in item['image']:
    if 'resource' in img:
      # You may want to do a more sophisticated test here
      # but this will do for an example
      img['resource'] = 'http://example.org'
with open('that_file', 'w') as datfile:
  datfile.write(dumps(dat, indent=4).strip('[]')) # Strip outer array braces in keeping with input. (Shrug)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
from StringIO import StringIO    
import re
import urllib

infile = open('test2.txt')
outfile = open('test4.txt', 'w')

pattern = r'"resource": ".+/(.+).jpg"'
replacement = '"resource": "../img/\g<1>.jpg"'
prog = re.compile(pattern)

for line in infile:
    if prog.search(line):
        url = line.split('"resource":')[1][2:][:-3]
        print(url)
    text = re.sub(pattern, replacement, line)
    outfile.write(text)
infile.close()
outfile.close
```

it works but I think it doesn't look pythonic at all

Comment: If it works, don't sweat it! AFAICT, `[2:][:-3]` in your case is the same as `[2:-3]`? Why do you need to import StringIO? Used elsewhere in your code?